# Declaring a c++11 thread mutex breaks cout

Tags: c++, powershell, git-bash, mingw-w64, stdthread

I just installed MinGW-w64 and I was trying to write a quick test to make see if I could build on my machine, and then run it on my brother's machine without a problem. Unfortunately, I didn't get that far.

The problem I'm having is that my code compiles fine, but if I run it on git bash, I get no output, and it skips my input. When I run it on Powershell, it works as expected. If I comment out a line (in the minimal version I'm posting here), it works fine on git bash as well as Powershell.

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

using std::mutex;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    cout << "Print the thing" << endl;
    cout.flush();
    mutex counterMutex; //If this is commented out, it works.
    cin.get();
}
```

Unfortunately, in the actual program, I want to do some multithreading, and I'll need mutexes, so just skipping them isn't an option.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: I assume the mutex used is `std::mutex`. You know a default constructed mutex is in an unlocked state? I think what you want to do is have `counterMutex` have a global lifetime (ex: global variable), and use `std::lock_guard` on your mutex before `cin`. I'm aware that has nothing to do with your problem, but who knows, maybe the problem will go away once you do it properly.